# Xcode Launch images screens for landscape app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, unity-game-engine

I'm developing universal app (game) which working only in landscape modes. Can I do not specify Launch images for portrait mode for saving size?

Comment: You could probably make an all-black png for Portrait, then run it through [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) to shrink it. I ran a 9KB Retina iPad image through ImageOptim and it shrank to 477 *bytes*.

Comment: The question is whether it is possible not to indicate  splash images for the portrait mode on ipad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding "Default-Landscape.png" will be enough, if you need so.

Answer (score 0):

"Universal apps must provide launch images for both the iPhone and iPad idioms".. BUT.. launch images for the iPhone are only accepted in portrait mode ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)).

so.. for `Default.png` or `Default-iphone.png` .. to provide a landscape launch image you must create the image and rotate it 90 degrees in an image editor